# What am i doing wrong with matplotlibs yticks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

My code is as follows (dont ask for the variable names, im german^^):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

strecke = []
zeit = []

daten = open("BewegungBeschleunigung.csv")

for i in daten:
    i =  i.strip().split(",")
    strecke.append(i[1])
    zeit.append(i[0])

zeit.pop(0)
strecke.pop(0)

f, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 100 + 1, 5)) 
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,6000, 10))
ax.set_xlabel("Zeit")
ax.set_ylabel("Strecke")

plt.plot(zeit, strecke, "go")
#plt.autoscale(enable = False, axis = "both", tight = None)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Now my Question is: As you can see in the picture , the y-axis only goes to 4860 instead of 6000 which is what I wrote and not in 10 steps (as what I wanted). It just goes in random steps. What am I doing wrong and why doesn't the x-axis go to 100?

thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: You should try setting the limits after plotting. So move `plt.plot(zeit, strecke, "go")` before setting the ticks

Comment: thanks for the help, but if im doing this it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/n0lvcp

Comment: Try the following: `ax.set_xlim(0, 101)` and `ax.set_ylim(0, 6000)` and then set the xticks and yticks and let me know what happens

Comment: where exactly do i have to add this? sry im a beginner, just somewhere in the code?

Comment: First `plt.plot(zeit, strecke, "go")`, then `ax.set_xlim(0, 101)` and `ax.set_ylim(0, 6000)` and then `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 100 + 1, 5))` and `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,6000, 10))`

Comment: it changes nothing, it looks exactly the same as before ^^

Comment: What is your maximum y-value. Try `print (max(strecke))`. If your maximum y-value is small like 100, 200 or so, then setting an upper limit of 6000 would make it look like the image you shared in the comment above. May be you need to just modify the values that appear as ticklabels. Without your datafile, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gBP3AU8r thats mine, should be at nearly 6000 (second column)

Comment: I would recommend to use numpy for loading: `zeit, strecke = np.loadtxt("BewegungBeschleunigung.csv", delimiter=",", unpack=True, skiprows=1)` This will also automatically circumvent the problem of string conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and after some hours I've found that my values were strigs:

```
ypoints=['97', '100', '98', '99', '55', '97', '100', '98', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '98', '100', '100']
```

I only did the following:

```
ypoints = [int(y) for y in ypoints]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I found was that your values were strings. You can convert them to floats while storing in lists. Then you can set the axis limits. Note that `np.arange(0,6000, 10)` would generate 600 ticks. This will overcrowd your y-axis.

```
for i in daten:
    i =  i.strip().split(",")
    strecke.append(float(i[1]))
    zeit.append(float(i[0]))
zeit.pop(0)
strecke.pop(0)

f, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel("Zeit")
ax.set_ylabel("Strecke")
ax.plot(zeit, strecke, "go")
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 6000)
ax.grid(True)
```

[image]