# gridspec without using ":" in Parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, codec

my Question is pretty simple: I cant do a ":" in the last parameter of 
diagram(strecke, strecke2, "Strecke in Metern/s", "S(t) Diagramm", 0, :)
because it tells me than: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
but i want to have this diagramm over both columns, so what can i do that its over both columns?

Link for the file: https://filehorst.de/download.php?file=ceCnteJq

```
import codecs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches # wird nicht benutzt, test
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.gridspec as grid

zeit = []
strecke = []
geschwindigkeit = []
beschleunigung = []
strecke2 = []
geschwindigkeit2 = []
beschleunigung2 = []


gs = grid.GridSpec(2, 2)
fig = plt.figure('Diagramme', tight_layout=True)

daten = open("BewegungBeschleunigung.csv")

reiheÜberspringen = True

for i in daten:

    if reiheÜberspringen == True:
        reiheÜberspringen = False
        continue

    i = i.strip().split(",")

    zeit.append(float(i[0]))
    strecke.append(float(i[1]))
    geschwindigkeit.append(float(i[2]))
    beschleunigung.append(float(i[3]))
    strecke2.append(float(i[4]))
    geschwindigkeit2.append(float(i[5]))
    beschleunigung2.append(float(i[6]))

def diagram(y, y2, yachse, titel, pos1, pos2):

    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[pos1, pos2])
    ax.plot(zeit, y, "go", markersize = 2.5)
    ax.plot(zeit, y2, "ro", markersize = 2.5)
    ax.autoscale(enable = False, axis = "both", tight = None)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_title(titel)

    plt.gcf().canvas.set_window_title("Diagramme")


diagram(strecke, strecke2, "Strecke in Metern/s", "S(t) Diagramm", 0, :)
diagram(geschwindigkeit, geschwindigkeit2, "Geschwindigkeit in Metern/s", "V(t) Diagramm", 1, 0)
diagram(beschleunigung, beschleunigung2, "Beschleunigung in Metern/s^2", "a(t) Diagramm", 1, 1 )
plt.show()



daten.close
```

Comment: I can only repeat [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266778/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-matplotlibs-yticks#comment97269917_55266778) here: use `numpy.loadtxt` to load your data.

Comment: Also please don't use links to data hosts in the future. The actual data used here is *completely* irrelevant for the problem. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an `if` condition inside your function. You can make the default value of `pos2` as `None`. So if you want `:`, you don't pass any value while calling `diagram`. Then you check inside the function, if any value has been passed for `pos2`. If not, then your use `:` else you use the passed value.

Below is the modified function. I don't have your data but it will work.

---

```
def diagram(y, y2, yachse, titel, pos1, pos2=None):
    if not pos2:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[pos1, :])
    else:    
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[pos1, pos2])
    ax.plot(zeit, y, "go", markersize = 2.5)
    ax.plot(zeit, y2, "ro", markersize = 2.5)
    ax.autoscale(enable = False, axis = "both", tight = None)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_title(titel)

    plt.gcf().canvas.set_window_title("Diagramme")


diagram(strecke, strecke2, "Strecke in Metern/s", "S(t) Diagramm", 0) # <-- No pos2
diagram(geschwindigkeit, geschwindigkeit2, "Geschwindigkeit in Metern/s", "V(t) Diagramm", 1, 0)
diagram(beschleunigung, beschleunigung2, "Beschleunigung in Metern/s^2", "a(t) Diagramm", 1, 1 )
plt.show()
```

Comment: ok, thank you but it comes another problem than. As you can see in this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/n170hh if i do it like this the V(t) diagram (the second one) is to big and gets over the a(t) diagram (the third one)

Comment: @BoroFel: What kind of problem?

Comment: sry pressed enter to fast, edited the comment with the problem

Comment: @BoroFel: Can you try adding `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()`?

Comment: it change nothing^^

Comment: Oh, then you will have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: so you mean you need the file? https://filehorst.de/d/ceCnteJq
                                                   https://filehorst.de/d/cCsiggGh
its the code and the file

Comment: Please also include this link in your question so that people reading it can help you

Comment: @BoroFel: Keine Uhrsache :)

Comment: Ursache* :P "Uhr" means clock ^^

Comment: @BoroFel: Ach so, genau :D

Answer (score 0):

Numpy provides a way to generate an indexing expression via [`numpy.s_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html). You may use it as

```
np.s_[:]
```

to pass the complete slice to a function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
fig = plt.figure('Diagramme', tight_layout=True)

data = np.loadtxt("data/BewegungBeschleunigung.csv", skiprows=1, delimiter=",", unpack=True)
(zeit, strecke, geschwindigkeit, beschleunigung, 
 strecke2, geschwindigkeit2, beschleunigung2) = data


def diagram(y, y2, yachse, titel, pos1, pos2):

    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[pos1, pos2])
    ax.plot(zeit, y, "go", markersize = 2.5)
    ax.plot(zeit, y2, "ro", markersize = 2.5)
    ax.autoscale(enable = False, axis = "both", tight = None)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_title(titel)

    plt.gcf().canvas.set_window_title("Diagramme")


diagram(strecke, strecke2, "Strecke", "S(t) Diagramm", 0, np.s_[:])
diagram(geschwindigkeit, geschwindigkeit2, "Geschwindigkeit", "V(t) Diagramm", 1, 0)
diagram(beschleunigung, beschleunigung2, "Beschleunigung", "a(t) Diagramm", 1, 1 )
plt.show()
```

[image]